# redirect m.php to m.domain.com htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

Is it possible to redirect

```
http://www.url.com/m.php?name=Bill
```

to

```
http://m.url.com/Bill/
```

via htaccess?

I have seen some examples but I'm not sure what
they use to accomplish that

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+m\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://m.url.com/%1/? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /m.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

assuming that both m.url.com and www.url.com point to the same document root.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for you reply. I get page unavailable when opening
http://m.url.com/Bill/

Comment: @user3772 dunno if it mattered, but I left out  a `/?` from the regex